# What can I change in this comprehension to remove brackets and quotation marks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get clean results in rows, but I don't know what my code is doing wrong. Comprehension gives me brackets and quotation marks which I don't want. I just simply want keys and values together.

```
# input()=rrbbbcc

for example: 
   r 2 
   b 3
   c 2
```

I've tried to change this:

```
   print(*[[k,v] for k,v in count.items() if v > 1],sep='\n')
```

but it's showing my result with brackets which I don't want.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        s = str(input())  # input() = aabbbccde
        count={}
        for i in s:
            count.setdefault(i, 0)
            count[i]=count[i]+1
        print([(k,v) for k,v in count.items() if v > 1], sep='')
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
   b 3
   a 2
   c 2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(list('rrrbbbcc'))
[print(*[k, v]) for k,v in x.items()]

>>> r 3
    b 3
    c 2
```

Edit:

---

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(list('rrrbbbcc'))
print('',*(' '.join([k,str(v),'\n']) for k,v in x.items()))

>>>
 r 3 
 b 3 
 c 2
```

Edit 2:

---

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(list('rrrbbbcc'))
print('',*[(yield from (k,str(v)+'\n')) for k,v in x.items()])

>>>
 r 3
 b 3
 c 2
```

Comment: Do not use list comprehension unless you plan to use the result. It isn't just a way to do a one line `for` loop.

Comment: I know that, however, the OP tried to achieve this in a list comprehension, and I showed how this can be done inside a list comprehension, so ...

Comment: Shouldn't have even been an option. List comprehension has its uses but this is not one of them. You are consuming memory for no reason other than to make it a one liner. Either loop it like glibdud's answer or use tuple unpacking inside a `print`.

Comment: Noted. Do you think there could be any other way to do it in list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

The most readable way would be to unwrap the comprehension and move the `print` function into the resulting for loop:

```
for k,v in count.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'are using Python 3, you can use Counter from collections package.
The code will be, something like this:

```
from collections import Counter 
input = 'rrrbbbcc'
counter = Counter(input)
for key, value in counter.items():
    print(f'{key} {value}')
```

Comment: Good answer but just a tip. It is easier to do code blocks using triple back ticks (the key below `esc` --> ```) then to space code blocks with 4 spaces. You can look at my edit of your question to better understand this :).

Comment: Thanx @Error-SyntacticalRemorse for the tip :)

Comment: can you make me understand about:- (f"{key} {value}"). what's the meaning of 'f'. Is there more datatype.

Comment: what's " counter "?

Comment: what ' counter ' does in str ?

Comment: @Rohit, f it's a new feature in python (fron version 3.6) called f-strings, this new feature give the possibility the create a string template and inject values into this string (something like **''.format()**). The Counter is a module of the package collections that create a dictionary over hashable objects (iterable, dictionary, ...) and count the occurence of each element in the objet you are passing to it (c.f [https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter])

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your print you can work on a list

```
x = [(k,v) for k,v in count.items() if v > 1] #get a list
x.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1]) #sort by count
x = x[::-1] #reverse sorting
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i][0], x[i][1])
```